# Ratchet Session storage

Tags: php, session, symfony, ratchet

I am newbie to Ratchet and Symfony both. I am trying to get familiar with them. I have used alternative to sessions which is quite weird but works. Here's it:

In JS (a native PHP session)

```
name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>";
msg = elem.value;
socket.send(name+"|"+msg);
```

The sent argument is then `explode` with delimiter `|`. It creates two strings. One is the name and other is msg which is then sent to all connections except the sender.

```
list($name, $message) = explode("|", $msg);
```

How can I use Symfony Session which saves nickname when user enters it and it will be accessible by my Chat class in MyApp namespace?

I have API docs but there is no simple example for using session. [**`API Documentation`**](http://socketo.me/api/namespace-Ratchet.Session.html).

### Tree:

```
/www
 |
 |___/src
 |    |
 |    |____/MyApp/
 |           |
 |           |___Chat.php // The Chat Class
 |
 |___/bin
 |     |
 |     |___chat-server.php
 |
 |___/vendor
 |
 |___/chat.php // <-- Chat Room, sending and receiving here
 |
 |___/index.php // <-- Ask for nickname here
 |
 |___/composer.phar
 |
 |___/composer.lock
 |
 |___/main.js // <-- Index HTML javascript
 |
 |___/socket.js // <-- Websocket handler for char.php
 |
 |___/main.css // <-- All style
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller can set the nickname to in the session:

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{nickname}")
 */
public function indexAction($nickname)
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('nickname', $nickname);
}
```

To retrieve the nickname in your Chat app,

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) 
{
    $nickname = $conn->Session->get('nickname');
}
```

Comment: Hey man! Thanks but I have to also include the Symfony session class, right? `use ....`

Comment: It is already attached to the controller class (via the service container) and ratchet connection (via ratchet).

Comment: Hey can you tell me in little newbie language ?

Comment: Not sure what you want me to say. Symfony sets up the session automatically and puts it in the controller for you. It's attached to the request in the controller, and the connection in your websocket Chat) app.

Comment: Let me edit the question with my directory tree. So, you can get how I am setting things up ;)

Comment: Edited! Everything is just like `Hello World!` tutorial but I have generated some HTML. Do I need to add my code also ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36990/discussion-between-muhammad-talha-akbar-and-mattexx)